# How to match "?" character in Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

When I visit `http://localhost/bill/detail/123?a=1&b=2`
I hope it redirect to `https://www.baidu.com/bill/detail/?a=1&b=2&term=123`

here is my config:

```
  location /bill/detail {
    rewrite  ^/bill/detail/([\d]+)\?(.*)$ https://www.baidu.com?$2&term=$1 redirect;
  }
```

but it shows does not match

```
2023/06/03 20:20:38 [notice] 3128#0: *5 "^/bill/detail/([\d]+)\?(.*)$" does not match "/bill/detail/1234", client: 127.0.0.1, server: 127.0.0.1, request: "GET /bill/detail/1234?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:5000"
```

Answer (score 0):

For your request try this:

```
location ~ /bill/detail/(?<term>\d+).*$ {
  return 301 http://www.domain.tld?a=$arg_a&b=$arg_b&term=$term;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i have known the reason, The ? and anything following is the query string and is not part of the normalised URI used by nginx in location and rewrite directives.